# Easier way in pythonnet to add/find nuget packages?

Tags: python, c#, python.net

I'm trying to call my C# assembly from Python.
Python is 3.9.7; .net is .net 5.

As this versions are not supported with the current pythonnet version I took the master and in principle it works.

My problem is that I have a bunch of nuget packages.
[image]

and pythonnet does not find them. This results in a general "Module XYZ not found" error in the line
`from XYZ import Foobar` (for example for Newtonsoft.Json)
or a `Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=5.0.0.0, ...` for example.

Do I really have to search every nuget package on disc and add

- `sys.path.append("C:\\Users\\xyz\\.nuget\\packages\\microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection\\5.0.2\\lib\\net5.0")`
- `clr.AddReference("Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection")`

or is there an easier way?

Maybe also important my first lines in python

```
from clr_loader import get_coreclr
from pythonnet import set_runtime

rt = get_coreclr("c:\\Temp\\runtimeconfig.json")
set_runtime(rt)


import clr
import sys
```

and the runtimeconfig.json

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "net5.0",
    "framework": {
      "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
      "version": "5.0.0"
    }
  }
}
```